# MVC 3, url parameter does not separate

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, web

I'm getting familiar with MVC 3. I got stuck on the first thing in the tutorial - unbelievable!

This is my Controller-method:

```
    public string Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1)
    {
        return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Hello " + name + ", NumTimes is: " + numTimes);
    }
```

And the url I'm using:

```
http://localhost:49770/HelloWorld/Welcome?name=Adam?numTimes=4
```

Which should produce this:

> Hello Adam, NumTimes is: 4

But it actually becomes this:

> Hello Adam?numTimes=4, NumTimes is: 1

It does not separate the params! It must be something really simple I've missed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got 2 question marks (?).  change the second one to an ampersand (&)

```
http://localhost:49770/HelloWorld/Welcome?name=Adam&numTimes=4
```

Comment: Hahaha, I'm laughing at myself! Of course you are correct. I'ts been a while since doing webb-stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Use `http://localhost:49770/HelloWorld/Welcome?name=Adam&numTimes=4`

The series of key/value pairs in a query string are separated with an ampersand.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string for details.

Answer (score 1):

When forming strings to send parameters, especially if you use JSON to do that with AJAX, in between each field sent must be an &. The & acts similar to a comma in method parameters. Whereas a call from code may be `Welcome("Adam",4)`, from a url it would look like `/Welcome?name=Adam&numTimes=4`. The ? tells MVC (assuming regular routing) to use the action found, in this case Welcome. Following that are name value pairs, separated by the & symbol.